# Java Servlet Filter Response Handling

Tags: java, servlet-filters

**Please note**: If anything about the answer to this question is implementation-dependent, then please assume latest/modern versions of either Tomcat or Jetty.

There are several details about the basics of [`java.servlet.Filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) that aren't covered in any of the tutorials I've read (such as [the official Oracle article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html#70176), [this one](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/servlet-filters.html) and [this one](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076050/java-web-development/filter-code-with-servlet-2-3-model.html)).

Specifically, there are two scenarios where the behavior of `doFilter` doesn't seem to be documented anywhere:

- When `doFilter` essentially does nothing (does not print anything to the `ServletResponse` nor invokes `FilterChain#doFilter`), what I call the **No-Op Filter**; and
- When `doFilter` prints a response to the `ServletResponse` **and** invokes `FilterChain#doFilter`, what I call the **Fire and Forget Filter**

For the No-Op Filter:

- If neither `FilterChain#doFilter` is invoked nor `ServletResponse` is written to, then I *assume* the filter blocks the request, yes?
- Either way, in this scenario, what is the HTTP status code returned?
- What is the entity sent back in the response? Empty?

For the Fire and Forget Filter:

- What happens when one both writes to the `ServletResponse` and invokes `FilterChain#doFilter`? An exception? Does the filter somehow cache the written response and then append to it when the upstream filters/resource return a response?
- What is the HTTP status code sent back?
- When a `ServletException` is thrown, does this automatically map to a HTTP 404 with the response entity of the exceptions's `getMessage()`?

Comment: Here is a link to the Servlet 3.1 specification: https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr340/index.html. You can either read the spec trying to find answers to your specific questions or you can download the reference implementation and run a simple test implementation to figure out what happens. Then you can run the same application with Tomcat and Jetty to see any differences.

Comment: Most of these questions are answered, often in the same language, in the [Servlet Specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr340/index.html). I suggest you read it and cut this multi-choice question down to the bits that remain unanswered.